# Erro 500 ao realizar uma requisição de autenticação com AdonisJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs

Eu possuo um SessionController, que na qual é o método que realiza o processo de autenticação do usuário na aplicação.

```
class SessionController {
  async store ({ request, response, auth }) {
    const data = request.all()
    const token = await auth.attemp(data.email, data.password)
    return token
  }
}
```

O meu routes.js, tbm possuo a instância desse método para mapeamento da API:

```
Route.post('/sessions', 'SessionController.store')
```

Os dados do usuário, já estão no Banco de dados, o problema é que, quando realizo o request, me retorna um erro 500.

Eu debuguei a aplicação, e me parece que a aplicação não roda depois da linha `const token = await auth.attemp(data.email, data.password)`.

Sem ideia alguma do que pode ser!

Answer (score 1):

Como o *status* do código é 500, provavelmente é um erro no código, veja:

Você escreveu o método `attempt` de forma incorreta. No seu código, há este trecho:

> `const token = await auth.attemp(data.email, data.password)`

De acordo com a [documentação](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_attemptuid_password_jwtpayload), o correto é:

```
const token = await auth.attemp(data.email, data.password)
```